# adjust rule thickness between row groups in a table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, rules, braces

How can I get the horizontal rule between group A and group B to be thicker without disturbing the braces? Do I need to use a different method to obtain the braces in order to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r}
    \begin{tabular}{|C{24pt}!{\vrule width1pt}C{20pt}|C{20pt}|}
    \hline
    a&b&c\\ \noalign{\hrule height1pt}
    \end{tabular}\\
    \llap{\hbox{group A}}
    \left\{
        \begin{tabular}{|C{24pt}!{\vrule width1pt}C{20pt}|C{20pt}|}
            1&2&3\\\hline
            4&5&6\\\hline
        \end{tabular}
    \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\\
    \llap{\hbox{group B}}
    \left\{
    \begin{tabular}{|C{24pt}!{\vrule width1pt}C{20pt}|C{20pt}|}
        7&8&9\\\hline
        7&8&9\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: row groups]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of `Xhline` defined in the `makecell` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}  % <---
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{r}
\begin{tabular}{|C{24pt}!{\vrule width1pt}C{20pt}|C{20pt}|}\hline
a&b&c\\
    \Xhline{1pt}   % <---
\end{tabular}\\
\llap{\hbox{group A}}\left\{\begin{tabular}{|C{24pt}!{\vrule width1pt}C{20pt}|C{20pt}|}
1&2&3\\ \hline
4&5&6\\ \Xhline{1pt}   % <---
\end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\\

\llap{\hbox{group B}}\left\{\begin{tabular}{|C{24pt}!{\vrule width1pt}C{20pt}|C{20pt}|}
7&8&9\\\hline
7&8&9\\\hline
\end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm thought I tried that and it didn't work but maybe something was different.  Super glad I didn't need to scrap the braces method.  Thank you!